# Change title css and area radius size in ImageMap of MS Chart

Tags: microsoft-chart-controls

How to change title element css of area element of imagemap which is there in MS Chart.

For i.e.

```
<map id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chtActivityImageMap" name="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_chtActivityImageMap">
      <area alt="" title="30-07-2013 : 600" coords="618,180,623,185" shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer">
      <area alt="" title="29-07-2013 : 400" coords="609,207,614,212" shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer">
      <area alt="" title="30-05-2013 : 1400" coords="80,70,85,75" shape="rect" style="cursor:pointer">
</map>
```

Here, it is the code of MS chart area. I want to change css of title element. And I also want to increase radius of area element when anyone hover on it.